# No symbols loaded in gdb?

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb, g++

Here is the error

```
g++ -o -g home debugTest.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: home: _ZSt4cout: invalid version 4 (max 0)
/usr/bin/ld: home: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: home] Error 1
```

What is very confusing is that this happens when i added `-g` after `-o`, but vice versa is okay. Tho i still get "no symbols loaded". Apparently without these symbols i cannot run `run` and i apparently need to run `run` do debug. This "external" debugging is only because i don't think debugging C++ withing VSC is doable so easy. You can see more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476496/debugging-c-in-visual-studio-code).

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is what i get when i run `gdb home` (home is executable) with a vice versa order of `-o` and `-g`.

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from home...
(No debugging symbols found in home)
(gdb)
```

Running `file` or `exec-file home` used to give me "no symbol in home" but now it asks me if i want to delete table for `file` or import new table for `exec-file`. When i went yes on latter i got same message `no debugging symbols`.

Comment: Please show the error message when you swap `-o` and `-g` as well.

Comment: I edited out what happens.

Comment: Did a file named `a.out` or `-g` get created in your build directory when you used `-o -g`?  Did `home` actually get updated in that case?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. At first the file `-g` got created, when the order of `-o` and `-g` wasn't right, i never created `a.out` it seems. As far as i recall, `home` stayed the same.

Comment: If you run `mv home home.backup; g++ -g -o home debugTest.cpp`, do you get any errors?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick Nope, not a single one.

Comment: OK, if you run `gdb home` now, does it still complain about debugging symbols not being found?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick Interestingly, no it does not! Now it says "reading symbols from home"! How did it get solved?

Comment: Somehow your old `home` file, which is now `home.backup` if you want to look at it, wasn't getting updated. Maybe your command before had a typo. Hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the order of options matters is that `-o` takes an *option argument* which is the name of the output file.  So when you type:

```
gcc -o -g home debugTest.cpp
```

you're saying to make, I want to generate an output file name `-g` and as inputs I want to use the files `home` and `debugTest.cpp`.  That's clearly not right.

You need to put the option argument next to the option it's an argument for, so it must be:

```
gcc -g -o home debugTest.cpp
```

or you can put it completely on the other side, like this:

```
gcc -o home -g debugTest.cpp
```

But you can't put something in between the option (`-o`) and its argument (`home`).

As for your debug problems, what is in the `debugTest.cpp` file?  If you run `./home`, what does it do?

**ETA**

I'm sorry but I can't reproduce your problem, so there must be something about your environment or system that you haven't communicated to us.  I took the source code you provided and tried it and it works fine:

```
$ g++ -g -o home debugTest.cpp

$ gdb home
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2.1
  ...

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from home...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/home
Name
[Inferior 1 (process 479404) exited normally]
(gdb) br main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5555555552c4: file debugTest.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/home

Breakpoint 1, main () at debugTest.cpp:6
6       int main(){
(gdb) n
7         std::string name = "Name";
(gdb) n
8         print(name);
(gdb) n
Name
9         return 0;
(gdb) n
7         std::string name = "Name";
(gdb) n
10      }
(gdb) n
0x00007ffff7be30b3 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function __libc_start_main,
which has no line number information.
[Inferior 1 (process 479447) exited normally]
(gdb) q
```

Comment: Okay, so `-o` argument and name of executable go always together, understood. About debug problems, it just prints simple "name" with a function. As i mentioned, there is source code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476496/debugging-c-in-visual-studio-code) and also the updates of what happen with inbuilt vsc debugger.

Answer (score 2):

`g++`'s `-o` option requires an argument, the desired name of the output file.  Per standard POSIX convention for command-line interpretation, and consistent with the `g++` docs as I read them, that must immediately follow the `-o` on the command line (POSIX would allow merging them into a single argument, but I don't think `g++` recognizes that).

It is incorrect to interpose another option between `-o` and its argument.  My expectation for your example is that `g++` would interpret `-g` as the name of the output file to create, but it's possible that it does something else, such as using `a.out`, the default output file name.  Either way, in that case I expect it to interpret `home` as the name of an *input* file.  It not being a C++ source file, it will simply be passed through to the linker as an object file or (presumably) shared library to include in the link.  That previously existing `home` is then the file you are trying to debug.  Presumably it was built without debug symbols and / or was stripped after it was built.

You may put the `-g` option after `-o`, but it must follow the output file name, too:

```
g++ -o home -g debugTest.cpp
```

The `-o home` must be considered a cohesive unit, not to be split up.